# ADF test - interpreting the results

Tags: augmented-dickey-fuller

I have a time series $x$ and I want to run the ADF test to check stationarity in the sense of unit root.
The series has lenght 60 so I apply lags from 1 to 11 as suggested by the literature (Schwert 1989).

In matlab I run:

`[h,p]=adftest(x,'lags',2:11)`

The output is:

> h =     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
>
> p =    0.7158    0.7889    0.6778    0.6989    0.6574    0.6658    0.6934  0.7161    0.6883    0.6855

How can I interpreter this result? The fact that h is zero shall be interpreted as It might not be stationary in the sense of the unit root. But the p-value is very high.

So can I conclude something or not?

Answer (score 1):

Well, I am also looking for answers related to the Dickey Fuller test but I know this much that a high p-value does indeed support the fact that your series is non-stationary. h=0 means that the test failed to reject the null hypothesis and your p-values also say exactly that.

Answer (score 0):

`h=0` here (in MATLAB) means that the ADF test fails to reject the null hypothesis of having a unit root.

You can conclude that the high $p$-values indicate that you cannot reject the unit root null hypothesis.